# SQLI tiemout issue specific to Azure/ClearDB node recycle

Tags: php, azure, mysqli, cleardb

When Azure/ClearDB recycle the principal My SQL node we are getting problems in our PHP programs even though we've got:

$timeout = 10;  /* seconds for timeout */
$mysqli->options( MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );

Is there some other parameter we should be setting as well to deal with this type of situation?

Comment: What specific problem do you get? Is the issue you get that the timeout setting is not working after you configuring it?

Comment: The PHP program is used with Twilio for telephone call handling.  Twilio reports HTTP failure due to timeout, resulting in call going to fall back url.

Comment: We are sure that standard timeout handling is working as had connection problems to ClearDB and the exception handling worked as expected.  The timeout issue was confirmed using My Sql Workbench

Comment: Could you check your clearDB status on this site? https://www.cleardb.com/status

Comment: We have regularly used the cleardb.com/status to check the status of the database but found that not to be reliable.  When ClearDB recycles a principal node they rarely post this to their status page, considering this to be 'routine maintenance' - even though it is being done during prime business hours and impacting users.   This is a known issue to Azure - we've submitted several tickets on this

Comment: The typical way we will find out about a node recycling is to open a ticket with ClearDB and they will report that in the ticket.

Comment: Here is an example from today where we had My Sql issues with Twilio, ClearDB did not update their status page, and our timeout handling did not catch:  Hello,
 
Thank you for contacting us,
 
Azure is recycling nodes in US-EAST2 region at the moment. Your database is a part of the cluster with nodes hosted in US-EAST2 region hence you may experience somewhat slower performance until the recycle completes. 
 
This is normal activity and will resolve soon. We apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: We were not able to resolve the problems using ClearDB and wound up migrating to a My Sql database entirely within Azure.  The following link should be of help to others looking to do the same:  MySQL Replication Template https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/mysql-replication